# An inequality about linear transformations

Tags: linear-algebra, inequality, linear-transformations

Is it true that : $$\inf_{x^2+y^2=1}\left(\left|\begin{pmatrix}a&b\\c&d\end{pmatrix}\begin{pmatrix}a'&b'\\c'&d'\end{pmatrix}\begin{pmatrix}x\\y\end{pmatrix}\right|\right)\geq\inf_{x^2+y^2=1}\left|\begin{pmatrix}a&b\\c&d\end{pmatrix}\begin{pmatrix}x\\y\end{pmatrix}\right|\cdot\inf_{x^2+y^2=1}\left|\begin{pmatrix}a'&b'\\c'&d'\end{pmatrix}\begin{pmatrix}x\\y\end{pmatrix}\right|$$
where all the variables are reals and $|.|$ denotes the euclidean norm. Can someone give a counterexample or confirm that this is true?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, it is true. Let $$M_1=\inf_{x^2+y^2=1}\left\lVert\begin{bmatrix}a&b\\c&d\end{bmatrix}.\begin{bmatrix}x\\y\end{bmatrix}\right\rVert\text{ and let }M_2=\inf_{x^2+y^2=1}\left\lVert\begin{bmatrix}a'&b'\\c'&d'\end{bmatrix}.\begin{bmatrix}x\\y\end{bmatrix}\right\rVert.$$

Let$$\begin{bmatrix}x'\\y'\end{bmatrix}=\begin{bmatrix}a'&b'\\c'&d'\end{bmatrix}.\begin{bmatrix}x\\y\end{bmatrix}.$$

Then\begin{align}\left\lVert\begin{bmatrix}a&b\\c&d\end{bmatrix}.\begin{bmatrix}a'&b'\\c'&d'\end{bmatrix}.\begin{bmatrix}x\\y\end{bmatrix}\right\rVert&=\left\lVert\begin{bmatrix}a&b\\c&d\end{bmatrix}.\begin{bmatrix}x'\\y'\end{bmatrix}\right\rVert\\&\geqslant M_1.\left\lVert\begin{bmatrix}x'\\y'\end{bmatrix}\right\rVert\\&=M_1.\left\lVert\begin{bmatrix}a'&b'\\c'&d'\end{bmatrix}.\begin{bmatrix}x\\y\end{bmatrix}\right\rVert\\&\geqslant M_1.M_2.\left\lVert\begin{bmatrix}x\\y\end{bmatrix}\right\rVert\end{align}
And now taking the infimum over the unit circle we have what we wanted.

Comment: Yes you are right. I should add that the matrix multiplication on the left is not zero.

Comment: Actually, my previous answer was wrong. WIth my previous example, your inequality was just $0\geqslant0\times0$. What do you think now?

Comment: I think that you proved the inequality only for that particular choice of $(x,y)$ which minimizes $\left|\begin{pmatrix}a'&b'\\c'&d'\end{pmatrix}\begin{pmatrix}x\\y\end{pmatrix}\right|$. With a slight modification I think its good.

Comment: I went through my proof and found no reason to change it. Where do you think that there is a mistake?

Comment: Well you say that $\begin{pmatrix}x'\\y'\end{pmatrix}=\begin{pmatrix}a'&b'\\c'&d'\end{pmatrix}\begin{pmatrix}x\\y\end{pmatrix}$ but you have fixed $(x,y)$. So anything that follows is for fixed $(x,y)$.

Comment: Sure. And where does that lead us?

Comment: That you proved the inequality only for that $(x,y)$.

Comment: I've edited my answer. What do you think now?